# Rails 4 - Where do vendor assets go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

After [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7968) in Rails, it is suggested that 3rd party assets should either be put in the `app/assets` folder or `config.precompile` should list all such assets.

Quoting a use case on that thread

> For example, if I need to vendor a jQuery plugin which also has CSS, a
>   font face, and an image sprite, I'd add the .js and .css to
>   vendor/assets/javascripts and vendor/assets/stylesheets. I would also
>   vendor the sprites and fonts in vendor/assets/images and
>   vendor/assets/fonts, respectively. Adding the entire vendor/assets
>   path seems overkill, but manually specifying each asset individually
>   seems tedious (though that might be by design).

Adding third party assets inside `app/assets` will lead to a Rails 2 *like* problem of a global assets folder.

Am I missing something ? Whats the Rails 4 way of organizing third party assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parties should be included by hand explicitly. This is because these libraries have many optional parts such as source code, readme files etc. If you need other things such as images or fonts you can add this files in public folder or do this:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif,
"fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
"fontawesome-webfont.eot",
"fontawesome-webfont.svg",
"fontawesome-webfont.woff")

config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

**environment/production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`.

Comment: Usually, when you add a third party JS lib you only add the `release`/`dist`version/folder, right ? You don't want to copy the source code of that anyways. And precompilation only picks up js, css anyways.

Comment: True. But in Rails 4 assets (CSS, a font face, and an image sprite, etc) in lib and vendor are no longer precompiled by default.

Comment: You should put this assets in your own app/assets to avoid unwanted files to be precompiled.

Comment: One thing which still works is putting a manifest `index.js` in the vendored libraries (in the vendor folder) telling Rails what to load. This way `your` code and `third party code` are in different places. See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) Section 2.2.2

Comment: So in summary, `require` works for vendor folder. `require_tree` doesn't, to prevent unwanted 3rd party files from being included. For that, create a manifest file as noted in the above comment above.